# Hide child component using data between siblings

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one parent and two child components. Child1 renders text. Child2 have a button. I need to hide child1 by pressing child2. I have tried to pass a function to child 2, but no luck so far. 
[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-shape-ovlf6)

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      visibility: true
    };
  }

  handleChildClick() {
    this.setState({
      visibility: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { visibility } = this.state;
    if (visibility) {
      return (
        <div>
          <ChildOne />
          <ChildTwo onClick={this.handleChildClick.bind(this)} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

class ChildTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClick}>Hide text</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your child two should be like

```
class ChildTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Hide text</button>
     </div>
    );
   }
 }
```

and render method of your parent component should be like

```
render() {
     const { visibility } = this.state;
     let firstChild=null;
     if (visibility) {
      firstChild=<ChildOne />
      }
  return (
    <div>
       {firstChild}
        <ChildTwo onClick={this.handleChildClick.bind(this)} />
       </div>
   ); 
  }
```

also you should define handleChildClick like,this will auto bind 'this' with the method

```
  handleChildClick=()=>{
    this.setState({
     visibility: false
   });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In `handleChildClick`, you need to call `this.setState` instead of just `setState`

```
  handleChildClick() {
      this.setState({
        visibility: false
      })
  }
```

And also you need to change `ChildTwo` to call the function from `props`

```
class ChildTwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Hide text</button>
     </div>
    );
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks for the tip, but still no luck.. [link] https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-shape-ovlf6

Answer (score 1):

Pass the handler function to child `<Button />` would work

Notice:

- `hooks` is only allowed to be used in functional components.
- for classical components, use `setState` instead, as the prev post said.
- you may don't want to use `bind(this)` every time you write a handler function, use [public class field syntax](https://github.com/ibarapascal/access-catalog/blob/master/blog/summary-of-react-develop-practice/summary-react.md/#function-binding-in-details) would be easier to maintain and acquire fewer performance costs.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isHidden: false
    };
  }
  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ isHidden: !this.state.isHidden });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {!this.state.isHidden && <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>}
        <Button onClick={this.onClick} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Button = props => {
  return <button onClick={props.onClick}> Button </button>;
};
```

---

[image]

Try it online

[image: Edit fervent-ramanujan-w4vcg]